# MySQL JSON "NOT In" is not working

Tags: mysql, json, notin

I have two tables where each on has its JSON column. I want to select the rows from the first one which are not in the second one and the search criteria is one of the properties of the JSON.

`Request.Details->'$.Key'` has the following data

```
"9523beaf-934b-e811-80d1-6a077df8507e"
"cf287991-434c-e811-80d1-6a077df8507e"
```

`Response.response->'$.Key'` has the following data

```
"9523beaf-934b-e811-80d1-6a077df8507e"
```

Now I tested this query:

```
select msr.`Details`->'$.Key' m
  from `Request` msr
 where msr.`Details`->'$.Key' in (select `response`->'$.Key' from `Response`);
```

It is working correctly and returns

```
"9523beaf-934b-e811-80d1-6a077df8507e"
```

But when I use `NOT IN` it returns an empty table.

```
select msr.`Details`->'$.Key' m
  from `Request` msr
 where msr.`Details`->'$.Key' not in (select `response`->'$.Key' from `Response`);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is very good and has everything necessary to answer it. I've edited it a little bit to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle `NULL`:

```
select msr.`Details`->'$.Key' m 
from `Request` msr 
where msr.`Details`->'$.Key' not in (select COALESCE(`response`->'$.Key','') 
                                     from `Response`)
```

As from [notin tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/notin/info):

> The NOT IN operator is the union of the "NOT" Logical Operator with the "IN" Comparison Operator. It can be used to specify multiple values that should NOT be present in a WHERE clause. **Note that NOT IN `<null>` never is true!**

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was with the data stored in both tables, some values were null while other were strings `NOT UUID` strings.

I guess that the InnodB tries to understand the format of the stored variable then process it and I do not see any reason for doing that since JSON objects are dynamics.